# What's the fast algorithm to check given board of nash's hex is ended?

Tags: algorithm

Refer this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)

I'm making Hex game, but I have no idea to check given game is ended.

So What the great algorithm check that given game is ended?

In here, ending means that exactly one person connect completely a line.

Question: Given positions of pieces of two players, What's the good algorithm to determine "Is there a complete line that makes game end?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an equivalence class data structure, sometimes known as a "union-find" structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

As each stone is placed, it is given a new equivalence class.  Then, the equivalence classes of that stone and all its neighbours of the same colour are merged.  Have "virtual stones" of each colour along each edge of the board.  When opposing edge stones of the same colour are in the same equivalence class, then a connection is made and the game is over.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Each piece has a side it's connected to (or no side), and is a part of a little cycle of pieces that are all connected. When a piece is placed, it checks if any adjacent piece is connected to a side, then links all adjacent cycles of pieces and adjusts their "side", if necessary. If it sees two sides, the game is over.

This is very similar to the algorithm used in go to determine if a group is captured.

Answer (score 0):

I Think A* is the right algorithm for you,
though it will be too straight forward, the computer will be playing very boring.

you can take a look at [A* Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)
or play with an implementation